# Problema com a exportação xls

Tags: javascript, microsoft-excel, export

Estou fazendo script de exportar uma tabela pro Excel, quando eu abro mostra `null`
segue o código:

```
function M(){
    var nProcesso = document.getElementById('nProcesso').value;
    var Autor = document.getElementById('Autor').value;
    var Reu = document.getElementById('Reu').value;
    var Data = document.getElementById('Data').value;
    var Especie = document.getElementById('Especie').value;
    var Vara = document.getElementById('Vara').value;




    document.getElementById('conteudo').innerText = "<table class='table' id='tblExport'>" + 
"<thead>" +
 "<tr>" +
    "<th>N° Processo</th>" +
    "<th>Autor</th>" +
    "<th>Reu</th>" +
    "<th>Data</th>" +
    "<th>Especie</th>" +
    "<th>Vara</th>" +
  "</tr>" +
"</thead>" +
"<tbody>" +
    "<tr>" +
    "<td>" + nProcesso + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + Autor + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + Reu + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + Data + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + Especie + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + Vara + "</td>" +
    "</tr>" 
+ "</tbody>" +  "</table>";

}
function ExportarExl() {
  let data = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);
  var texto = document.getElementById('tblExport').innerText;
  let titulo = document.getElementById('nProcesso').value;
  var blob = new Blob([texto], { type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8" });
  saveAs(blob, titulo + " " + data + ".xls");
}
```

Função `saveAs`:

É um componente que pode ser encontrado [neste Git](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js).

**Código:**

```
/*
* FileSaver.js
* A saveAs() FileSaver implementation.
*
* By Eli Grey, http://eligrey.com
*
* License : https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/LICENSE.md (MIT)
* source  : http://purl.eligrey.com/github/FileSaver.js
*/

// The one and only way of getting global scope in all environments
// https://stackoverflow.com/q/3277182/1008999
var _global = typeof window === 'object' && window.window === window
  ? window : typeof self === 'object' && self.self === self
  ? self : typeof global === 'object' && global.global === global
  ? global
  : this

function bom (blob, opts) {
  if (typeof opts === 'undefined') opts = { autoBom: false }
  else if (typeof opts !== 'object') {
    console.warn('Deprecated: Expected third argument to be a object')
    opts = { autoBom: !opts }
  }

  // prepend BOM for UTF-8 XML and text/* types (including HTML)
  // note: your browser will automatically convert UTF-16 U+FEFF to EF BB BF
  if (opts.autoBom && /^\s*(?:text\/\S*|application\/xml|\S*\/\S*\+xml)\s*;.*charset\s*=\s*utf-8/i.test(blob.type)) {
    return new Blob([String.fromCharCode(0xFEFF), blob], { type: blob.type })
  }
  return blob
}

function download (url, name, opts) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhr.open('GET', url)
  xhr.responseType = 'blob'
  xhr.onload = function () {
    saveAs(xhr.response, name, opts)
  }
  xhr.onerror = function () {
    console.error('could not download file')
  }
  xhr.send()
}

function corsEnabled (url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  // use sync to avoid popup blocker
  xhr.open('HEAD', url, false)
  try {
    xhr.send()
  } catch (e) {}
  return xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status <= 299
}

// `a.click()` doesn't work for all browsers (#465)
function click (node) {
  try {
    node.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'))
  } catch (e) {
    var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents')
    evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 80,
                          20, false, false, false, false, 0, null)
    node.dispatchEvent(evt)
  }
}

var saveAs = _global.saveAs || (
  // probably in some web worker
  (typeof window !== 'object' || window !== _global)
    ? function saveAs () { /* noop */ }

  // Use download attribute first if possible (#193 Lumia mobile)
  : 'download' in HTMLAnchorElement.prototype
  ? function saveAs (blob, name, opts) {
    var URL = _global.URL || _global.webkitURL
    var a = document.createElement('a')
    name = name || blob.name || 'download'

    a.download = name
    a.rel = 'noopener' // tabnabbing

    // TODO: detect chrome extensions & packaged apps
    // a.target = '_blank'

    if (typeof blob === 'string') {
      // Support regular links
      a.href = blob
      if (a.origin !== location.origin) {
        corsEnabled(a.href)
          ? download(blob, name, opts)
          : click(a, a.target = '_blank')
      } else {
        click(a)
      }
    } else {
      // Support blobs
      a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href) }, 4E4) // 40s
      setTimeout(function () { click(a) }, 0)
    }
  }

  // Use msSaveOrOpenBlob as a second approach
  : 'msSaveOrOpenBlob' in navigator
  ? function saveAs (blob, name, opts) {
    name = name || blob.name || 'download'

    if (typeof blob === 'string') {
      if (corsEnabled(blob)) {
        download(blob, name, opts)
      } else {
        var a = document.createElement('a')
        a.href = blob
        a.target = '_blank'
        setTimeout(function () { click(a) })
      }
    } else {
      navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(bom(blob, opts), name)
    }
  }

  // Fallback to using FileReader and a popup
  : function saveAs (blob, name, opts, popup) {
    // Open a popup immediately do go around popup blocker
    // Mostly only available on user interaction and the fileReader is async so...
    popup = popup || open('', '_blank')
    if (popup) {
      popup.document.title =
      popup.document.body.innerText = 'downloading...'
    }

    if (typeof blob === 'string') return download(blob, name, opts)

    var force = blob.type === 'application/octet-stream'
    var isSafari = /constructor/i.test(_global.HTMLElement) || _global.safari
    var isChromeIOS = /CriOS\/[\d]+/.test(navigator.userAgent)

    if ((isChromeIOS || (force && isSafari)) && typeof FileReader === 'object') {
      // Safari doesn't allow downloading of blob URLs
      var reader = new FileReader()
      reader.onloadend = function () {
        var url = reader.result
        url = isChromeIOS ? url : url.replace(/^data:[^;]*;/, 'data:attachment/file;')
        if (popup) popup.location.href = url
        else location = url
        popup = null // reverse-tabnabbing #460
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
    } else {
      var URL = _global.URL || _global.webkitURL
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      if (popup) popup.location = url
      else location.href = url
      popup = null // reverse-tabnabbing #460
      setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(url) }, 4E4) // 40s
    }
  }
)

_global.saveAs = saveAs.saveAs = saveAs

if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = saveAs;
}
```

Comment: e o código da function `saveAs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem 2 problemas no seu código:

1. `document.getElementById('conteudo').innerText`

O `.innerText` irá enviar para o elemento o conteúdo em texto puro, ou seja, as tags HTML serão imprimidas em texto e não interpretadas como tags pelo navegador. Além do que o código na função `ExportarExl()` não irá achar a id `#tblExport`. O correto é usar `.innerHTML`, desta forma: `document.getElementById('conteudo').innerHTML`.

2. Na função `ExportarExl()`, a variável `texto` possui o mesmo problema usando `.innerText`, quando deveria usar `.outerHTML` para pegar a div e a tabela completa (não apenas o conteúdo interno), ou seja: `var texto = document.getElementById('tblExport').outerHTML;`

**Exemplo de teste:**

```js
/*
* FileSaver.js
* A saveAs() FileSaver implementation.
*
* By Eli Grey, http://eligrey.com
*
* License : https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/LICENSE.md (MIT)
* source  : http://purl.eligrey.com/github/FileSaver.js
*/

// The one and only way of getting global scope in all environments
// https://stackoverflow.com/q/3277182/1008999
var _global = typeof window === 'object' && window.window === window
  ? window : typeof self === 'object' && self.self === self
  ? self : typeof global === 'object' && global.global === global
  ? global
  : this

function bom (blob, opts) {
  if (typeof opts === 'undefined') opts = { autoBom: false }
  else if (typeof opts !== 'object') {
    console.warn('Deprecated: Expected third argument to be a object')
    opts = { autoBom: !opts }
  }

  // prepend BOM for UTF-8 XML and text/* types (including HTML)
  // note: your browser will automatically convert UTF-16 U+FEFF to EF BB BF
  if (opts.autoBom && /^\s*(?:text\/\S*|application\/xml|\S*\/\S*\+xml)\s*;.*charset\s*=\s*utf-8/i.test(blob.type)) {
    return new Blob([String.fromCharCode(0xFEFF), blob], { type: blob.type })
  }
  return blob
}

function download (url, name, opts) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhr.open('GET', url)
  xhr.responseType = 'blob'
  xhr.onload = function () {
    saveAs(xhr.response, name, opts)
  }
  xhr.onerror = function () {
    console.error('could not download file')
  }
  xhr.send()
}

function corsEnabled (url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  // use sync to avoid popup blocker
  xhr.open('HEAD', url, false)
  try {
    xhr.send()
  } catch (e) {}
  return xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status <= 299
}

// `a.click()` doesn't work for all browsers (#465)
function click (node) {
  try {
    node.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click'))
  } catch (e) {
    var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents')
    evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 80,
                          20, false, false, false, false, 0, null)
    node.dispatchEvent(evt)
  }
}

var saveAs = _global.saveAs || (
  // probably in some web worker
  (typeof window !== 'object' || window !== _global)
    ? function saveAs () { /* noop */ }

  // Use download attribute first if possible (#193 Lumia mobile)
  : 'download' in HTMLAnchorElement.prototype
  ? function saveAs (blob, name, opts) {
    var URL = _global.URL || _global.webkitURL
    var a = document.createElement('a')
    name = name || blob.name || 'download'

    a.download = name
    a.rel = 'noopener' // tabnabbing

    // TODO: detect chrome extensions & packaged apps
    // a.target = '_blank'

    if (typeof blob === 'string') {
      // Support regular links
      a.href = blob
      if (a.origin !== location.origin) {
        corsEnabled(a.href)
          ? download(blob, name, opts)
          : click(a, a.target = '_blank')
      } else {
        click(a)
      }
    } else {
      // Support blobs
      a.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href) }, 4E4) // 40s
      setTimeout(function () { click(a) }, 0)
    }
  }

  // Use msSaveOrOpenBlob as a second approach
  : 'msSaveOrOpenBlob' in navigator
  ? function saveAs (blob, name, opts) {
    name = name || blob.name || 'download'

    if (typeof blob === 'string') {
      if (corsEnabled(blob)) {
        download(blob, name, opts)
      } else {
        var a = document.createElement('a')
        a.href = blob
        a.target = '_blank'
        setTimeout(function () { click(a) })
      }
    } else {
      navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(bom(blob, opts), name)
    }
  }

  // Fallback to using FileReader and a popup
  : function saveAs (blob, name, opts, popup) {
    // Open a popup immediately do go around popup blocker
    // Mostly only available on user interaction and the fileReader is async so...
    popup = popup || open('', '_blank')
    if (popup) {
      popup.document.title =
      popup.document.body.innerText = 'downloading...'
    }

    if (typeof blob === 'string') return download(blob, name, opts)

    var force = blob.type === 'application/octet-stream'
    var isSafari = /constructor/i.test(_global.HTMLElement) || _global.safari
    var isChromeIOS = /CriOS\/[\d]+/.test(navigator.userAgent)

    if ((isChromeIOS || (force && isSafari)) && typeof FileReader === 'object') {
      // Safari doesn't allow downloading of blob URLs
      var reader = new FileReader()
      reader.onloadend = function () {
        var url = reader.result
        url = isChromeIOS ? url : url.replace(/^data:[^;]*;/, 'data:attachment/file;')
        if (popup) popup.location.href = url
        else location = url
        popup = null // reverse-tabnabbing #460
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(blob)
    } else {
      var URL = _global.URL || _global.webkitURL
      var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      if (popup) popup.location = url
      else location.href = url
      popup = null // reverse-tabnabbing #460
      setTimeout(function () { URL.revokeObjectURL(url) }, 4E4) // 40s
    }
  }
)

_global.saveAs = saveAs.saveAs = saveAs

if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = saveAs;
}
function M(){
    var nProcesso = "123";
    var Autor = "autor";
    var Reu = "reu";
    var Data = "07/07/2014";
    var Especie = "esp";
    var Vara = "segunda";




    document.getElementById('conteudo').innerHTML = "<table class='table' id='tblExport'>" + 
"<thead>" +
 "<tr>" +
    "<th>N° Processo</th>" +
    "<th>Autor</th>" +
    "<th>Reu</th>" +
    "<th>Data</th>" +
    "<th>Especie</th>" +
    "<th>Vara</th>" +
  "</tr>" +
"</thead>" +
"<tbody>" +
    "<tr>" +
    "<td>" + nProcesso + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + Autor + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + Reu + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + Data + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + Especie + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + Vara + "</td>" +
    "</tr>" 
+ "</tbody>" +  "</table>";

}
function ExportarExl() {
  let data = new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);
  var texto = document.getElementById('tblExport').outerHTML;
  let titulo = "tit";
  var blob = new Blob([texto], { type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8" });
  saveAs(blob, titulo + " " + data + ".xls");
}
```

```html
<div id="conteudo"></div>
<button onClick="M()">Gerar tabela (clique aqui primeiro)</button>
<button onClick="ExportarExl()">Exportar Excel</button>
```

Comment: O conteúdo do arquivo exportado é um texto do html puro: (não faz diferença innerHtml ou innerText).
<table class="table" id="tblExport"><thead><tr><th>N° Processo</th><th>Autor</th><th>Reu</th><th>Data</th><th>Especie</th><th>Vara</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>123</td><td>autor</td><td>reu</td><td>07/07/2014</td><td>esp</td><td>segunda</td></tr></tbody></table>

Comment: Sam, muito obrigado, deu certo aqui...estou apanhando no js, não sei muitas coisas, mas obrigado por me ajudar

Comment: @GuiAmericana de nada. Se puder marcar a resposta com ✔ a comunidade agradece ;)

Comment: @Elizeu há muita diferença entre innerText e innerHTML. Como eu disse, o primeiro retorna texto puro, inclusive tags. Sendo assim o código `document.getElementById('tblExport')` não vai achar o elemento com a id #tblExport porque ele não irá existir como elemento.

Comment: @Elizeu o que tem a ver com o tempo da resposta e o da pergunta? Não entendi a sua colocação.

Comment: @Elizeu Se vc tem uma resposta melhor, tem a liberdade e o direito de postar. Ganhará até +1 meu se for boa (nem precisa ser melhor ou pior que a minha).

Comment: @Sam, como eu faço para ele ir adicionando na linha de baixo, cada vez que eu preencho o formulário?

Comment: @Sam, como eu faço para ele ir adicionando na linha de baixo, cada vez que eu preencho o formulário?

Comment: @GuiAmericana Tem que adicionar apenas linhas na tabela, e não a tabela inteira. Coloque a estrutura da tabela com o tbody vazio no HTML e vai adicionando apenas linhas, como mostra aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/b2x3ksqt/

Comment: @Sam, voce é top, parabéns.. você é 10

Comment: @Sam, estou com um problema em outro script... você pode me ajudar?

Comment: @GuiAmericana se estiver ao meu alcance.

Comment: @Sam, estou com script que o botão copy e botão salvar, no localhost funciona agora na hospedagem não. segue o link http://servicequalityscript.000webhostapp.com/

Comment: Abre o codigo lá e da uma olhada

Comment: @Sam, o botão Salvar eu conseguir usando a biblioteca que voce me passou, o botão copiar que não esta funcionando servicequalityscript.000webhostapp.com